# IntelliJ Alt-Q shows method name in a temporary popup but can it be made permanent like phpStorm does?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I can see Alt-Q as a temporary popup, but is there a way to get the method name permanently at the top of the code in the same way phpStorm does?

Answer (score 0):

Just a workaround: you can press Alt-Q twice